# Salesforce - Files images not showing in communities

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, images

I've been trying to make images appear in Communities for a while and I cannot seem to make it work. I can see them when I log in the community as SysAdmin, but not as a user.

I've tried to play with any setup I could find to open those. A list of all the obvious checks is below to help troubleshoot.  I suspect there is a permission or something similar playing somewhere but I've spent two days trying to find the right setup with no luck.

(note: I am in a dev instance, not sure if that changes anything).

Key point: all images are rendering from a Lightning Web Component. The component itself is working fine for all users, just not rendering the images for community and comm + users.

All images are stored as Salesforce Files and in a library. For those, I am using the servjet link to access them with the prefix needed for communities: LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_260, FIND( '/services',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_260))  + '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/' + {imageId}

For any image, I can see them fine when logged as admin, but not as community user. When I log as community user, I just have the broken image icon.

Current setup
Org-wide default:

1. Image - External set to Public Read Only
2. Asset - External set to Public Read Only
3. Cannot find the settings for Content Document or Files in Sharing Setting

Profiles:
Community users have a dedicated profile which, among other things, has:
Select Files from Salesforce : True
Files Connect Cloud : True
Salesforce Files - Connected App Access : True

In addition, the Community has the box Let guest users view asset files and CMS content available to the community  set to True.

Finally, I have also tried to share manually via the libraries, to see if that would work. Users with Community + license can see the images in the library from the community site, but not via the LWC that renders them.

Does anyone know what I can do to enable images in communities for community users?

Thanks a lot for any help!